# Accessing server on Internet

Tags: server, internet

how do I access my server on the internet? I would want it to have a domain of piezosystems.com, accessed on internet but not public. My router has a IP adress of 10.0.0.1, comcast, and my server 10.0.05, cannot route it to internet. Please help.

Answer (score 1):

The 10.0.0.x range is reserved for private local networks. These addresses are not public internet addresses.

Your machines are behind a NAT firewall. You need to configure your firewall to route the ports you want to the machines inside your network, and discover your machines gateway address from your router configuration

IP addresses issued to home ISP customers are typically dynamic - they will change without notice. Registering a domain to such an address has it's own special challenges. In addition, most domestic ISP contracts forbid you to run a commercial service from your connection.

The domain you want is already registered, although it's "on hold". The entity holding the registration has probably acquired it speculatively in the expectation that they can extract a good price from someone who wants it.

I think you need to learn more about how TCP/IP networks work, how the DNS system works, and you need to obtain a commercial ISP service, or a hosted server from a company specializing in such things.